# creating an interleave_lists linked list?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create a linked list function called `IntNode *interleave_lists(IntNode *head_1, IntNode *head_2);` that takes two linked list, combines them and return a pointer to the head.

example: suppose head_1 points to a linked list containing three integers: 1, 3, 5, and head_2
points to a linked list containing 5 integers: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. The new linked list will contain 8
integers, in this order: 1, 10, 3, 11, 5, 12, 13, 14.

I have these structs to help create the linked list:

```
struct intnode {
   int value;
   struct intnode *next;
};
typedef struct intnode IntNode;

IntNode *intnode_construct(int value, IntNode *next)
{
   IntNode *p = malloc(sizeof(IntNode));
   assert (p != NULL);
   p->value = value;
   p->next = next;
   return p;
}
void print_linked_list(IntNode *p) //for printing linked list
{
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("empty list");
        return; 
    }

    /* Print every node in the linked list except the last one,
       using the format: value1 -> value2 -> value3 -> ...
     */
    for (; p->next != NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%d -> ", p->value);
    }

    /* Print the last node. */
    printf("%d", p->value);
}
```

now trying to create the function I have:

```
IntNode *interleave_lists(IntNode *head_1, IntNode *head_2)
{
    int count = 1;
    IntNode *p1=head_1, *p2=head_2,*head=NULL;
    for(; (p1->next != NULL) || (p2->next != NULL); p1 = p1->next, p2 = p2->next){
        if(p1 != NULL && count == 1){
            head = intnode_construct(p1->value,head);
            count = 0;
        } else if(p2 != NULL && count == 0){
            head = intnode_construct(p2->value,head);
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

but every time I run it the console displays CRT: unhandled exception (main) -- terminating.
My test case for this function:

```
int main(void)
{
    IntNode *list1 = NULL,*list2 = NULL; // An empty linked list.
    list1 = intnode_construct(5, list1);
    list1 = intnode_construct(3, list1);
    list1 = intnode_construct(1, list1);

    list2 = intnode_construct(14, list2);
    list2 = intnode_construct(13, list2);
    list2 = intnode_construct(12, list2);
    list2 = intnode_construct(11, list2);
    list2 = intnode_construct(10, list2);


    IntNode *head = NULL;

    head = interleave_lists(list1, list2);
    print_linked_list(head);
}
```

Comment: On which line does the crash occur?  If you don't know, use a debugger to find it.

Comment: I guess `p->next = next;` should be `p->next = NULL;`

Comment: As an aside, you *could* make the interleave function operate on the existing lists if you wanted, to avoid copying all the nodes.  Depends if you want to retain the original lists afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems

- You check `p->next != NULL` rather than `p != NULL`, so you lose the last element of the list
- Your loop checks `p1 || p2`, looping as long as either pointer hasn't yet reached the end.  So if the lists are different lengths, the pointer for the short list will run off the end and crash.
- your `intnode_construct` function constructs lists from right to left (tail to head), but you iterate from head to tail, so you are reversing the lists as you interleave them.

The reversing lists thing means you need to interleave from the tail, making your `interleave_lists` function much easier to implement recursively:

```
IntNode *copy_list(IntNode *head)
{
    if (!head) return head;
    return intnode_construct(head->value, copy_list(head->next));
}

IntNode *interleave_lists(IntNode *head_1, IntNode *head_2)
{
    if (!head_1) return copy_list(head_2);
    return intnode_construct(head_1->value, interleave_lists(head_2, head_1->next));
}
```

Alternately, you can do a 'destructive' interleave, reusing the nodes of the input lists:

```
IntNode *interleave_lists(IntNode *head_1, IntNode *head_2)
{
    if (!head_1) return head_2;
    head_1->next = interleave_lists(head_2, head_1->next);
    return head_1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Your `intnode_construct` should be like below

```
IntNode *intnode_construct(int value, IntNode *next)
{
   IntNode *p = malloc(sizeof(IntNode));
   if (p != NULL)
   {
       p->value = value;
       p->next = NULL;
   }
   return p;
}
```

With your code, the loop `for(; (p1->next != NULL) || (p2->next != NULL);` in function `interleave_lists` never ends because of `->next` will never be `== NULL`.

**2)** Your `interleave_lists` must be like below:

```
IntNode *interleave_lists(IntNode *head_1, IntNode *head_2)
{
    int count = 1;
    IntNode *p1=head_1, *p2=head_2,*head=NULL;

    while ((p1 != NULL) || (p2 != NULL))
    {
        if(p1 != NULL && count == 1)
        {
            head = intnode_construct(p1->value,head);
            count = 0;
            p1 = p1->next;
        }
        else if(p2 != NULL && count == 0)
        {
            head = intnode_construct(p2->value,head);
            p2 = p2->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Your code always move both pointer to next in each loop, without checking if pointer is valid or `NULL`.

**3)** BTW you must correct your code to have the head of each linked list. Your code update pass to `interleave_lists` the last element...